# accessing java object saved in hazelcast from python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In our application, we are saving data in hz maps from a java app and down the line a python app needs to access that data. Data is saved in object form. How can we access these java objects from python module.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement one of [IdentifiedSerializable](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#identifieddataserializable) or [Portable](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-portable-serialization) serialization methods for your classes on both side.

And see [this](http://hazelcast.github.io/hazelcast-python-client/3.8/serialization.html) for python serialization.

Comment: it populating the data from python only, In my scenario data is populated by some other java application which i have to read.Hope I am clear what I want to communicate